MongoDB Date Conversion Problem for "London/Europe" TimeZone in Azure Function C#
In my Azure Function, I configured environment variable WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE as Europe/London, hosted this on Azure Linux App Service Plan with "North Europe Zone" and in my base class, I created Date Objects as below:
public class BaseService
{
    public DateTime Yesterday { get; set; }
    public DateTime Today { get; set; }

    public BaseService()
    {
        SeedData();
    }

    private void SeedData()
    {
        // Configure Processing Dates
        bool isManul = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(ConfigConstants.IsManual).ExactBool();            
        DateTime processingDate = isManul ? Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(ConfigConstants.ManualDate).ExactDateTime() : DateTime.Now;

        Yesterday = processingDate.AddDays(-1);
        Today = processingDate;
    }
}

In another service that is inherited by this base class, I'm using these date objects to query MongoDB
public class MyService : BaseService
{
   var filter = fd.Gte(FieldConstants.CreatedDate, Yesterday.Date)
     & fd.Lt(FieldConstants.CreatedDate, Today.Date);
   ////
}

Here, I observed that in MongoDB log (Assuming Today is "27-jun-2024") the Query utilized wrong Date with TimeZone issue:
Expected
"query": {
    "processedDate": {
       "$lt": {
       "$date": "2024-06-26T00:00:00Z"
     }
   }
 },

Actual
"query": {
    "processedDate": {
       "$lt": {
       "$date": "2024-06-25T23:00:00Z"
     }
   }
 },


Does this answer your question? Creating a DateTime in a specific Time Zone in c#
